# Thumbnails loading forever

Tags: thumbnails

Suddenly this happens: the thumbnails of my home page (which is a list of blog posts) suddenly take forever to load. Literally forever (they never load). But even this is not totally accurate: sometimes they just load fine. It seems like 70% of the times they keep loading forever and 30% they load just fine. Which leaves me completely baffled.

Some additional info that might or might not be related:

1) I used regenerate thumbnails and nothing changed;

2) I'm using the free Cloudflare service;

3) the picture displays just fine once you click on a post (the full size img).

Any ideas what can I look at?

Comment: Could you link to the live site? Note that WordPress typically doesn't participate in serving static files to visitors, they are passed up and handled by web server.

Comment: To me that sounds like a CDN/Cloudflare issue or your hoster does not allow that connection (or something between like state restrictions in Iran, China, Turkey etc. - depends on where your server lives). Anyway, we will need to have a bit more info. Please file an [edit] to your question.

Comment: Please describe method used for testing 'literally forever'.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking the images are hosted on Cloudflare's CDN? Have you tried using a different browser to see if the issue still persists?

Also, if you provide a link, other users could validate if they have the same issue.